# Reusing a component in another page redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Redux noob here. I would appreciate any feedback and knowledge. I'm pretty much building a instagram clone. I have a `Post` component that is currently set up to `HomePage`. I want to reuse `Post` component along with its sub components `Like` and `Delete` in `ProfilePage`. I prop drill my post data from `HomePage` -> `Post` -> `Like` and `Delete`. My user data from `local storage` in `Post` -> `Like` and `Delete`, same with `ProfilePage`. When i try to like or delete a post from my `ProfilePage` it works, its just that it doesn't update the state. So i only see the results once i refresh. I have my `HomePage` actions like `Like` and `Delete` in my `postReducer`. I only use the `userReducer` to fetch the users posts on `ProfilePage`. I've scoured here and saw something about redux connect but the post is 5 years old. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps you to understand the structure - https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your problem is your data doesn't changes after an event .
You can solve this by using componentDidChange on classes and useEffet in functional component with mentioning the data which changes and then the component will re render once the mentioned data is changed.Or you can go with componentwillrecieveprops a redux method the runs once the data in the redux store changes.

Comment: I've tried useEffect but doesn't work. I'll try the others you recommended.